# Can I implement Paypal with a combination of website payment standards & Paypal API?

Tags: paypal

In my application I have implemented the Paypal website payment standards.  But when I use it I can't retrieve details for recurring users. Can I use the API to do the job? Is this a valid or meaningful method?

Comment: if you're dealing with paypal, you're already using their api...

Comment: No iam using website payment standards method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no you can't retrieve the  standard subscription. But you could use the paypal API to make the recurring payments.

http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/526264/How-to-create-recurring-profile-with-express-check#answer1

the above link will provide you the code to create it.

Tip:-
The mentioned code first create a Sales account and then convert it in to the recurring account

Comment: if you had any doubt feel free to ask me. I will share what i know about it.

Answer (score 1):

With standard subscriptions you can't access those via the API.  If you want to work with subscriptions via the API you'll need to use the Recurring Payments platform instead of Payments Standard.